# Complex Angular script

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating divs based on ng-repeat. I'm getting the data from a db. The data is like:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name:item1,
        category: [catA, catB, catC,]
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:item2,
        category: [catB]
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:item3,
        category: [catA, catB]
    }
]
```

This data goes in a scope. So:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){

    var cat = "catA";

    $http.get("/getdata", function(response){
        if(response.data){
            $scope.items = response.data;

            if(response.data.category==cat){    // Check if the var cat is present in the array. How to do this?
                //set ng-class for the button in the div to 'active'. How to do this?
            }

        } else {
            $scope.message = "Nothing returned.";
        }
    });

    $scope.send = function(n){
        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
   }
});
```

I'm using ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="myclass">
        {{item.name}}
        <button class="myRight" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="send(item.id)"> click </button>
</div>
```

Active Class:

```
.active { background: #FF735C; color:white;}
```

So, based on the `var cat` present in the array of `category` received in the data, the class of the button is decided. And if the button is clicked, the class toggles. I cannot use $index for the button to pass the var as if the data is filtered, the proper index is not rendered.

Am I right to use ng-class? Is there any other simpler way to achieve this?

Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: So to confirm, the button should be `active` if the item has `catA` as a category and not `active` once the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. And if a item does not have `catA` like `item2`, the button in this div should be not have the active class.

Comment: If an active button is clicked, does it then become 'inactive' and is unable to be clicked again?

Comment: Thanks. No, its just a class. The button is clickable again. Only the class toggles. I added the class in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this should solve your problem, `ng-class` is definitely the right way to go.

```
// our store of active buttons/items
$scope.buttonActive = {};

$http.get("/getdata", function(response)
{
    if (response.data)
    {
        angular.forEach(response.data, function (item)
        {
            // create a list of active items based on if it has a category
            $scope.buttonActive[item.id] = item.category.indexOf(cat) !== -1;
        });

        $scope.items = response.data;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.message = "Nothing returned.";
    }
});

/**
 * @param id
 */
$scope.send = function (id)
{
    // toggle the boolean value for this button/item's state
    $scope.buttonActive[id] = !$scope.buttonActive[id];
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="myclass">
    {{ item.name }}
    <button class="myRight" ng-class="{ 'active': buttonActive[item.id] }" ng-click="send(item.id)">click</button>
</div>
```

UPDATE

`if` statements essentially work by evaluating one or more conditions to a boolean value.

```
if (true)
    doSomething();
```

So what I'm doing on that line is this:

```
// if item.categories array contains the category in 'cat' variable
if (item.category.indexOf(cat) !== -1)
    $scope.buttonActive[item.id] = true;
else
    $scope.buttonActive[item.id] = false;
```

But seeing as I'm assigning a boolean value depending on another boolean value, I may as well just use the result of the initial condition.

```
var isInArray = item.category.indexOf(cat) !== -1;

$scope.buttonActive[item.id] = isInArray;
```

Or just:

```
$scope.buttonActive[item.id] = item.category.indexOf(cat) !== -1;
```

Comment: What is this magic called? `$scope.buttonActive[item.id] = item.category.indexOf(cat) !== -1` 
Where can I learn more about it?